# How to type check if a object property has a value then other property should have value with respective to this one

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

How to type check in a object that if one property has a specific value the other property should have value with respective to this one in typescript ?

```
const StatusTypes = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Failed',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Awaiting',
  },
] as const;

export type StatusId = typeof StatusTypes[number]['id']; 
export type StatusName = typeof StatusTypes[number]['name'];

export interface Status = {
id:StatusId; // How to make sure if StatusId = 1 
name:StatusName; // it should only be 'Failed'
desc:string;
count:number|null
}
```

Comment: Please include the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), not an image

Comment: [Please replace images of code/logs/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218). Right now this question is not appropriate for Stack Overflow and might be closed as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: make an union type

```
export type Status1 = typeof StatusTypes[number] & {
    desc: string;
    count: number | null
}
```

Option 2: make an generic type

```
export interface Status2<Id extends typeof StatusTypes[number]['id']> {
    id: Id,
    name: Extract<typeof StatusTypes[number], { id: Id }>['name'],
    desc: string;
    count: number | null
}
```

---

side note:
It may be cleaner to keep types as a map rather then an array

```
type StatusTypes = {
    1: { id: 1, name: 'Failed', },
    2: { id: 2, name: 'Awaiting', },
    3: { id: 3, name: 'Running', },
    4: { id: 4, name: 'Processed', },
}
```

Consider this depending on your environment and type sources